# Create forecast from series

Tags: graphite

I have some time series in graphite and I'd like to do a forecast of how the series will continue into the future.

It feels really simple. Append the changes from the last 7 days to the current time making it stretch 7 days into the future.

But I've found nothing. It doesn't even look possible to have the x/time-axis stretch into the future.

Is this really not possible?

Comment: Did you look at the graphite functions for this: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.holtWintersForecast

Comment: I did try holt winter but got nothing out of it. It seems to do something else

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible natively in Graphite although you could use it with R to do this. Here's one example.

https://roidelapluie.be/blog/2015/05/13/r-and-graphite/